# Django queryset field replaced with related table field

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-models

I have 2 tables (Product and CustomerProduct)

CustomerProduct is the intermediate table between Customer and Product. It assigns customer specific pricing to certain products.

#### Product Model

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
```

sample data

| id | name | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | orange | 1.5 |
| 2 | apple | 2.2 |
| 3 | kiwi | 3.5 |

#### CustomerProduct Model

```py
class CustomerProduct(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        "Customer",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="customer_customerproducts",
    )
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        "Product",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="product_customerproducts",
    )
    price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=12,
        decimal_places=2,
    )
```

sample data

| id | customer_id | product_id | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 233 | 1 | 1.2 |
| 2 | 233 | 2 | 2.0 |

#### Expected Result

I want to query the all products but the Product.price adjusted according to CustomerProduct.price if related field exists. The expected data (example in json but want queryset):

```
[
    {
        id: 1
        name: "orange"
        price: 1.2 // The price adjusted according to customer price
    }
    {
        id: 2
        name: "apple"
        price: 2.0 // The price adjusted according to customer price
    }
    {
        id: 3
        name: "kiwi"
        price: 3.5 // Price remain original because CustomerProduct not exists.
    }
]
```

#### The How

I totally have no idea how to accomplish this in Django. How to do that?

Comment: Your model code would be helpful...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat you mean not helpful enough? mind letting me know which model, i change it. tqvm

Comment: I meant to say please [edit] and add your models code to the question... (Surely you have some code along the lines of `class Product(models.Model): ...`, which I would say is highly relevant to your question)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat make sense. Updated

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Coalesce` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) with [Subquery expressions [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) to annotate a value on your queryset which will be the price that you want. `Coalesce` gives the first non-null value of the expressions passed to it, so we will pass it a subquery that will get the related price from `CustomerProduct` or the field `price` itself in that order to achieve what you want:

```
from django.db.models import F, OuterRef, Subquery
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce


customer = Customer.objects.get(pk=some_pk)  # get the customer for which you want the results

# Last related price, will use it as a subquery
related_price = CustomerProduct.objects.filter(
    product=OuterRef('pk'),
    customer=customer,
).order_by('-pk').values('price')[:1]

products = Product.objects.annotate(
    price_offered=Coalesce(
        Subquery(related_price),  # If there is a matching object in the subquery use it
        F('price'),  # Else use the price of the Product itself
    )
)

for product in products:
    print(product.pk, product.name, product.price_offered)
```